# Callback for Video Upload

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-opengraph

I am working on an application (in C#) that uploads a video to Facebook using the Graph API HTTP POST request. As part of the workflow, I need to get the URL of the video source once uploaded. What I am noticing however is when I upload the video via HTTP POST, it can take up to an hour for FB to process the video and for it to appear as an object within the graph API that I can query and get the source property. 
So I can avoid writing a timer that constantly queries the API for the existance of the object - does anyone know of any callback functionality within the FB Graph API that can notify my application once video processing has finished and the video object is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you not get the video ID back at upload time? If you do, you can query this in the API periodically until the video URL is returned in the response:
e.g.`http://graph.facebook.com/2031763147233`

Comment: Yes I get the URL returned - but video processing times have been over an hour - so I was hoping for the API to have some kind of callback event, instead of having to continually poll Facebook waiting for the video to be processed.

Comment: If you subscribe to the user's feed connection you'll be pinged when the video completes as far as I know: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/ 
Caveat: it will also be pinged for other updates, so maybe in your specific case polling is more appropriate